# grid.arrange plots do not retain the same dimensions even with same y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, image-resizing

I am trying to plot the following [Mean difference plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZm2B.png) with the following code:

```
colors <- c("Mean Growth Difference" = "red", "VIX" = "blue2")

x_axis_labels <- (2005:2019)
y_axis_labels<- (-4:2)

g1<- ggplot(diff2,                            
       aes(x = Period,
           y = mean)) +
 
   geom_line(aes(color ="Mean Growth Difference"))+ 
   geom_line(data = diff2, aes(x = Period, y = std_VIX,color ="VIX"),linetype = "dashed") +
   geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = down, ymax = up),fill="indianred1", color="NA", alpha = 0.09) +
   theme_classic() + 
   labs(x = "Year",
        y = "(%) Growth Difference / Standardized VIX ",
        color = "Legend") +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
   scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
   scale_x_continuous(labels = x_axis_labels, breaks = x_axis_labels)+
   scale_y_continuous(labels = y_axis_labels, breaks = y_axis_labels)+
  theme(legend.position="none")

g2<- ggplot(dif2,                      
      aes(x = Period,
          y = mean)) +
 
 geom_line(aes(color = "Mean Growth Difference"))+ 
 geom_line(data = dif2, aes(x = Period, y = std_VIX,color ="VIX"),linetype = "dashed") +
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = down, ymax = up),fill="indianred1", color="NA", alpha = 0.09) +
 theme_classic() + 
 labs(x = "Year",
      y = "(%) Growth Difference / Standardized VIX ",
      color = "Legend") +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
 scale_color_manual(values = colors) +
 scale_x_continuous(labels = x_axis_labels, breaks = x_axis_labels)+
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = y_axis_labels) + 
 theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
       axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
 theme(legend.position="none")
```

Using the grid.arrange to position them side by side:

```
gr1 <- ggplotGrob(g1)
gr2 <- ggplotGrob(g2)

newWidth = unit.pmax(gr1$widths[2:3], gr2$widths[2:3])

gr1$widths[2:3] = as.list(newWidth)
gr2$widths[2:3] = as.list(newWidth)

grid.arrange(gr1, gr2, ncol=2)
```

**However, as you might notice in the picture linked above, the size of the y-axis is smaller in the second graph even though its scale is exactly the same. How can I correct this issue?**

Extra points for those that tell me how to annotate in a way that the annotations don't move/resize when adding the plots to grid arrange.

Comment: Why don't you use facets (eg. facet_wrap()) instead of making two plots? Alternatively try patchwork package for combining plots

Comment: Thank you Richard. I see that facet_wrap works by plotting non-overlapping groups (eg. a dummy or categorical variable). In my case i the groups i have to plot have overlapping data. How would you proceed?

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: Dear Quinten, i added sample data. Thank you for your help

Comment: combine the two datasets with bind_rows(). Use the .id argument to identify the dataset and facet by this. something like bind_rows(diff2 = diff2, dif2 = dif2, .id = "what") |> ggplot(...) + geom_xxx() + facet_wrap(~what)

Comment: Thank you Richard! Everything worked out perfectly. I don't understand how I could not figure this out myself. Kudos